# How to save Image in directory folder in Oracle (not Blob in database)

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a Form like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyTJW.png

I am saving the file path in database but I also want to save image file in server folder. Can any one share query or function in Oracle format?

Here is my code so far

```
DECLARE 
    a            varchar2(20);--2018
    v_directory  varchar2(200);--mkdir D:\EMP\2018
    filename varchar2(256); --D:\img.doc    
    v_last_slash_position NUMBER;--3    
    v_file_name VARCHAR2(30);--img.doc
    v_extension VARCHAR2(4);--.doc        
    v_last_slash_position2 NUMBER;--7
    path2 VARCHAR2(30);--D:\EMP\2018
    v_file_name2 VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
    SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYY')
    INTO a 
    FROM dual;

    v_directory:='mkdir D:\EMP\'||a;  
    filename := get_file_name(File_Filter=>'JPEG Image (*.JPG,*.JPEG,*.JPE,*.JFIF)|*.JPG|');

    v_last_slash_position := INSTR(filename, '\', -1) + 1;
    v_file_name := SUBSTR(filename, v_last_slash_position);
    v_extension := SUBSTR(filename, -3);

    v_last_slash_position2 := INSTR(v_directory, '\', 1) - 2;
    path2 := SUBSTR(v_directory,7);
    v_file_name2 := path2||'\'||v_file_name;

    host(v_directory,NO_SCREEN);
    MESSAGE(filename);
    MESSAGE(v_file_name2);

    --    HOST('cmd /d COPY '||filename||' '||v_file_name2,NO_SCREEN); This is not working
    IF NOT Form_Success THEN 
    MESSAGE('Error -- File not copy.');
    ELSE 
    MESSAGE('Success.');  
    END IF; 
END;
```

Thanks in Advance

[1]:

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [Ask] and take the [Tour].

Comment: You have an image. You want to store it into a directory on a hard disk. Why is Oracle (a *database* management system) involved into that operation? What's wrong with your operating system capabilities to do such a task?

Comment: @Littlefoot - this is not an unreasonable question, given that Oracle supports a BFILE datatype.

Comment: You mean, *my* question is not unreasonable, @APC? :) I've seen more than often that people use inappropriate tools for certain tasks; that's why I asked.

Comment: @Littlefoot - fair point. As you know I meant the OP's question is a reasonable one. When applying change to both the database (storing the path) and the OS (storing the file) some component needs to be in charge. As a database zealot I'm happier when it's the database :)

Answer (score 5):

In PL/SQL you can use this procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SaveFile(
   FileContent IN OUT NOCOPY BLOB
   , FolderName IN VARCHAR2
   , FileName IN VARCHAR2)
IS

    BUFFER RAW(1024);
    OFFSET PLS_INTEGER := 1;
    FileLength PLS_INTEGER;
    amount PLS_INTEGER := 1024;
    fhandle UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;

BEGIN

    FileLength := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(FileContent);
    fhandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(FolderName, FileName, 'wb');          
    LOOP
        EXIT WHEN OFFSET > FileLength;
        DBMS_LOB.READ(FileContent, amount, OFFSET, BUFFER);
        UTL_FILE.PUT_RAW(fhandle, BUFFER, TRUE);
        OFFSET := OFFSET + amount;
    END LOOP;
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (fhandle);

EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        IF UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(fhandle) THEN
            UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fhandle);
        END IF;
    RAISE;

END SaveFile;
```